# insert key-values to associative array in php from file

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I can't insert values from file into php associative array. Can anyone help?
The code is below, look at 3rd array item, I'd like to insert key-values from file, but every time I get en error. How to do that? (include, echo, or function result - doesn't work inside array!). How to do that?

```
<?
$somedeclaredvaiable = '0 => "value1", 1 => "value2", 2 => value3", 3 => "value4", 4 => "value5", 7 => 4';

$a = array(
1 => array(
   0 => "value1",
   1 => "value2",
   2 => "value3",
   3 => "value4",
   4 => "value5",
   7 => 4

),
2 => array(
   0 => "value1a",
   1 => "value2a",
   2 => "value3a",
   3 => "value4a",
   4 => "value5a",
   7 => 4
),
3 => array(
//THE PROBLEM IS HERE, can't include file, or echo an variable!
include 'filewitharray.txt';  //doesn't work
echo $somedeclaredvariable ;  //doesn't work
),
);

?>
```

Comment: Include the file before your array declaration! You can't call functions that return void within an array definition, and both include and echo do such

Comment: How cool is that you mention what error are you getting?

Insert `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` top of your code after `<?php` and post the error.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code is syntactically incorrect :

```
3 => array(
//THE PROBLEM IS HERE, can't include file, or echo an variable!
include 'filewitharray.txt';  //doesn't work
echo $somedeclaredvariable ;  //doesn't work
),
```

Assuming that `filewitharray.txt` is a php file that would be returning an array (or something else), like this :

```
<?php
    return array('foo' => 'bar');
```

Then, you could do :

```
$a[] = require 'filewitharray.txt';
```

It will add the variable returned by `filewitharray.txt` into your table.

If `filewitharray.txt` is not supposed to be PHP code and you want the content of the file to be added into the array (as a string), then you could do :

```
<?php

$a[] = file_get_contents('filewitharray.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it now.

```
<?php

  include 'filewitharray.txt';

    $somedeclaredvaiable = '0 => "value1", 1 => "value2", 2 => value3", 3 => "value4", 4 => "value5", 7 => 4';



    $a = array(
    1 => array(
       0 => "value1",
       1 => "value2",
       2 => "value3",
       3 => "value4",
       4 => "value5",
       7 => 4

    ),
    2 => array(
       0 => "value1a",
       1 => "value2a",
       2 => "value3a",
       3 => "value4a",
       4 => "value5a",
       7 => 4
    ),
    3 => array(



    ),
    );

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get the contents of the file beforehand:

```
$included = file_get_contents("file with array.txt");
```

Then in your array declaration:

```
...snip
3 => array(
    $included, $somedeclaredvariable
)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

my filewitharray.txt file is:

     0 => "This road marking warns",
     1 => "drivers to use the hard shoulder",
     2 => "overtaking drivers there is a bend to the left",
     3 => "overtaking drivers to move back to the left",
     4 => "drivers that it is safe to overtake",
     7 => 3

and I want to include it:

    3 => array(
    //HERE (include filewitharray.txt here)
    )
    );


without using $somedeclaredvariable - this was an example

Could you please give some your sugestions?

I get :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include that information? Also, as a heads up, PHP won't naively parse that file as an array; your best option would be to have serialized the array when you saved it originally and unserialized it here